# What does `(?:| ...)` mean in a Ruby regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

While reading *Engineering long-lasting software: an Agile approach using SaaS and cloud computing* I came across the following regex (Chapter 5, Section *5.3 Introducing Cucumber and Capybara*):

```
/^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/
```

I know about the non-capturing `(?: ...)` syntax, but what I don’t understand is the meaning of the first pipe character after the colon. Is it a typo? Does it serve any particular purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipe in regex means alternative. In this case, it is expressing alternation between an empty string `""` and the string `"I "`.

Comment: Wow... so obvious. Looking at the answer provided by @Wrikken, why is it that `(?:|I )` is not equivalent to `(?:I )?` ?

Comment: @Alf: Because the empty string is tried first, and `"I "` only if necessary. For example `(?:|a)a` would match the string `aa` twice; `(?:a)?a` only once.

Comment: Testing in `irb` I get the following: `> md1 = "aa".match /(?:|a)a/  => #<MatchData "a">` whereas `> md2 = "aa".match /(?:a)?a/  => #<MatchData "aa">`.

Comment: @Alf Tim is correct. Since your `md1` matches `"a"`, the same regex can match the string again, matching twice in total. With second one, `md2` matches `"aa"`, so it matches the string only once.

Comment: In that case, wouldn’t `md1.post_match` return the empty string? `> md1.post_match   => "a"`, as if the second a hasn’t been matched.

Comment: That is because you did `match`. If you do it with `scan`, for example, then the last `post_match` will be an empty string.

Comment: I was about to reply to myself with the same comment. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is just the `or`. It can match either nothing or `I` (with a space). The rest is non-capturing group like you mention.

The regex matches something like `I am on a diet` and also `am on a diet` and in the above examples, captures `a diet` in the first group.

Try it out on Rubular - http://rubular.com/r/q3RFEoxj1e

Answer (score 0):

`(?:|something)`

*("nothing / empty string or the match")*

Is exactly the same thing as:

`(?:something)?`

*("the match, once or none")*

In other words: the non-capturing subpattern is optional.

Comment: Not quite. It's the same as `(?:something)??`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Hm, is this ruby-specific (close to no experience with Ruby myself), or am I missing something else?

Comment: Ah, I see your explanation at the accepted answer, I understand now, thank you ;)

Comment: @Wrikken: Apart from the meaning, you need to make sure the behavior is equivalent. `??` will try empty string before `something`, which is the same as `(|something)`, while `?` will try `something` before empty string due to greedy property.